# Replace jmx_exporter_config.xml in the Docker image built by Fabric8 maven plugin

Tags: jmx, prometheus, fabric8

The default Docker image that is being built using `mvn package fabric8:build` contains `/opt/agent_bond/jmx_exporter_config.xml` that doesn't include (filters out) JMX beans that I'm interested in exporting to the Prometheus.

How can I replace that file with my own during the build with Fabric8 maven plugin?

I know I can construct the Docker image from scratch or redefine everything using Fabric8 plugin XML config, but that's too invasive in comparison to the default "Zero-config" approach.

**Update:**

So one way I found is to add custom `jmx_exporter_config.yml` file to the `src/main/fabric8-includes` and then add environment variable via Kubernetes deployment in `src/main/fabric8/deployment.yml`:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        -env:
          - name: AB_JMX_EXPORTER_CONFIG
            value: /deployments/jmx_exporter_config.yml
```

Unfortunately, the Docker image in this case would still not expose custom metrics by default.

I also cannot add exposed ports when using Spring Boot generator "zero-configuration" option.

**Update 2**

So the workaround for the ENV entry works ok and probably is sufficient for my use case.
The 4th port that I was trying to expose was the Spring Boot management port (default 8081). But it seams that it is not needed for the Kubernetes liveness probe checking, since Kubelet can access that port even if it is not exposed from the Docker image of the Spring Boot service.

Comment: When you say it doesn't expose custom metrics by default, do you mean that the agent doesn't pick up the config file ?

Comment: The agent picks up the /opt/agent-bond/jmx-exporter-config.yml from the fabric8 basis image. This file filters out all MBeans out except those related to Camel. How can I replace this file with mine?

Comment: When you start the application, how does the first line in the log looks like ? (check with `kubectl logs`) This shows the java command used. Also you could `kubectl exec -it` into your pod to check whether the file is indeed in place and whether the env is set.

Comment: My goal is Docker image.
When I start Docker image locally, I get:
exec java -javaagent:/opt/agent-bond/agent-bond.jar=jolokia{{host=0.0.0.0}},jmx_exporter{{9779:/opt/agent-bond/jmx_exporter_config.yml}} -cp . -jar /deployments/spring-boot-mongo-starter-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
I> No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://172.17.0.4:8778/jolokia/
2017-03-29 22:34:24.308:INFO:ifasjipjsoejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2017-03-29 22:34:24.352:INFO:ifasjipjsoejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9779

Comment: As the environment variable `AB_JMX_EXPORTER_CONFIG` is set in the Kubernetes deployment descriptor it will only be set when deploying on Kubernetes. In order to add this env to your Docker image you need to add it to the image configuration (or provide it with `docker run -e ...` when starting). Actually, the fabric8-maven-plugin is intended to be used for a Kubernertes / OpenShift use case scenarion, not so much for running plain Docker image. There are plans to move the generator ("zero config") feature to docker-maven-plugin so that it can be used there, too.

Comment: Everything you specify in a Dockerfile's `EXPOSE` is only metadata (and e.g. used for `docker -P ..`) and is not directly connected to the ports you bind to with your application. You can bind to any port and connect to them, even when not mentioned in `EXPOSE`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe is currently the recommended way, but it should be probably easier to add such config files.

For the "zero-config" mode you can set this in the configuration (so not so zero ;-):

```xml
<configuration>
   <generator>
     <config>
       <spring-boot>
          <webPort>8080</webPort>
          <!-- dont expose jolokia -->
          <jolokiaPort>-1</jolokiaPort>
          <prometheusPort>9999</prometheusPort>
       </spring-boot>
     </config>
   </generator>
</configuration>
```

If you need additional ports you would have to provide it in your resource yaml fragment. See also https://maven.fabric8.io/#generator-java-exec for the options you can use here.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this.
The example config does not allow to add additional port to the 3 exposed by fabric8 in the docker image.
I have tried to create src/main/fabric8/deployment.yml file as suggested here https://maven.fabric8.io/#resource-fragments and here
https://github.com/rhuss/fabric8-maven-plugin/blob/master/samples/external-resources/src/main/fabric8/deployment.yml

I could not neither get AB_JMX_EXPORTER_CONFIG env var set in the Dockerfile nor could I expose 4th port from the docker image.

Comment: Everything in the resource descriptors are only applied during _runtime_, not _build_ time. So when you don't use Kubernetes or OpenShift it won't be of any help for you. There is currently no way to set environment variables during build time by using generators, but you can always add a dedicated `<images>` configuration on your own. But then, and if you don't use Kubernetes / OpenShift, the recommended plugin is fabric8/docker-maven-plugin

Comment: but if I use <images> I automatically lose the automatic generator support and need to describe all image details by myself (up to java command line, jar packaging, filesystem locations copying, etc.)